# Storing a BLOB(Image) File using Visual Basic to MS Access

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, blob, oledb

How can I store/update a BLOB/Image file in MS Access using Visual Basic? I can do the basic queries like selecting, updating and deleting, and it's my first time that I'm going to use BLOB in MS Access. Assuming that the image file to be stored is shown in a picturebox.

Comment: This [**article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257) is robably what you are looking for.

Comment: Does Access have a `varbinary` data type, or some type of byte array?

Answer (score 0):

In common case, storing a BLOB/Image file in MS Access is not a good idea.

Comment: Yep. because it makes the database slow.

Comment: It depends on the file size.  For small files, it's actually faster than saving to disk most of the time.  I think that around 256K, saving to disk starts to become the faster option.  DISCLAIMER:  This is based on my experience with SQL.  My experience with Access is minimal.